# How to protect JSON data from selenium interceptor?

Tags: javascript, json, selenium, encryption

I have a simple html/css/javascript webpage frontend communicating JSON data back and forth with a restful api backend. Besides basic network encryption such as https, I'm looking for some mechanism to encrypt the JSON data so that any request/response interceptor can only see the encrypted strings and hackers can't easily get the encryption key (if exists) from frontend javascript source code. Is this even possible? I'm fully aware of the "frontend encryption is strongly discouraged" cliche, so thank you in advance for not repeating that:)

Comment: Most people here wont find that key in webpacked js tbh.

Comment: Any tutorial? Thanks.